# Why does touchesBegan not fire when the number of touches changes?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, touchesbegan, touches

For some reason my touchesBegan method doesn't seem to be responding correctly. If I touch the screen with two fingers, then lift one up and put it down again, touchesBegan gets called correctly. If I touch the screen with one finger, then add a second finger, touchesBegan does not get called like it should. Is there some flag that I need to check? Below is a sample that illustrates my problem:

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
     NSLog(@"touch");
}
```

Any ideas what's going on? I'm testing on an iPad with iOS 4.2 if it matters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you need to set the [multipleTouchEnabled](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/setMultipleTouchEnabled:) property on your view.

> When set to NO, the receiver receives
>   only the first touch event in a
>   multi-touch sequence. The default
>   value of this property is NO.

Comment: Awesome. I thought I checked that value, but it turns out I didn't have it set. Either way, I don't think I understood what that flag actually did in the first place. Thanks.